# An easier way to create multiple objects of the same class

Tags: java, class, methods

I have a Player class with all the setters & getters.

I have to read in 5 Players from the keyboard which I'm fine with but when creating the :

```
Player player1 = new Player();
```

Then asking for all the inputs.

Is there any way I can just increment the 1 to make a Player2, Player3, etc.

I have tried the ++ method. I don't properly know what exactly it what I'm asking for. Sorry in advance for the confusion.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    Player player1 = new Player();
    player1.getSurname();
    player1.getFirstName();
    player1.getAge();
    player1.getHeight();
    player1.getRank();

    Player player2 = new Player();
    player2.getSurname();
    player2.getFirstName();
    player2.getAge();
    player2.getHeight();
    player2.getRank();

    Player player3 = new Player();
    player3.getSurname();
    player3.getFirstName();
    player3.getAge();
    player3.getHeight();
    player3.getRank();
```

Comment: Create a hash or array of players instead of separate variables for each.

Comment: Am i going about this the wrong way completely then?

Comment: Well not entirely wrong. You can do it in a loop. Use an array as Dave said, Player [] players = new Player[10];

Comment: No, it's fine. Just create an array (or `List`) of `Player` and extract the code of `Player` creation in a separate method. Then call this method in a `for` loop.

Comment: For future questions please make your titles more informative. That helps others with their searches.

Comment: Yes sorry i wasn't sure exactly what i was asking for. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Self documenting code is preferable. `get` methods should simply `return` a value, not perform an action, such as user input.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

int NUM_PLAYERS = 5;

ArrayList<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();

for (int i = 0; i < NUM_PLAYERS; i++) {
    Player p = new Player();

    System.out.print("Surname: ");
    String surname = in.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Firstname: ");
    String fname = in.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Age: ");
    int age = in.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Height: ");
    int height = in.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Rank: ");
    int rank = in.nextInt();

    p.setSurname(surname);
    p.setFirstName(fname);
    p.setAge(age);
    p.setHeight(height);
    p.setRank(rank);

    System.out.println("Current Player \n" + p);
    players.add(p);
    in.nextLine(); // clear the buffer
}

System.out.println("All players");
System.out.println(players);
```

---

Use a full model object and `set` methods to actually assign the data

```
public class Player {

    private String surname;
    private int height;
    private int rank;
    private int age;
    private String firstName;

    public String getSurname() {

        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(int height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    public int getRank() {
        return rank;
    }

    public void setRank(int rank) {
        this.rank = rank;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Player{" +
                "surname='" + surname + '\'' +
                ", height=" + height +
                ", rank=" + rank +
                ", age=" + age +
                ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: ah yes i see now. thankyou :) I had a bigger list of : Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
 public void setSurname(String newSurname){
  surname = newSurname;
 }
 public void setFirstName(String newFirstName){
  firstName = newFirstName;
 }
 public void setAge(int newAge){
  age = newAge;

Comment: BTW, you should really check the Scanner `hasXXX` functions before calling the `nextXXX` functions... `if (in.hasNextInt()) age = in.nextInt();` otherwise they will throw an `InputMismatchException` error. Or, at least, catch the error.

Comment: Personally, yes, I *would* do that in a production app, but I literally coded this answer in maybe 2 minutes, sooo yeah...

Answer (score 1):

You could do this.

```
List<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();
```

Then you could loop in and add players. Checkout ArrayList [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can make an array of `Player` objects

```
Player[] players = new Player[5]; //creates an array that can hold 5 Player objects
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  players[i] = new Player();
  player.getSurname();
  //place rest of code here
}
```

Comment: thankyou. I am still getting an error "player cannot be resolved". I have all the setters and getters in a Player class, is this correct?, Actually my constructor is called Player - Cannot make a static ref to a non static field. grrrr ;)

Comment: @JamesFogarty where are you trying to access the variable from? Also make sure you're using the same variable name.

Answer (score 1):

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
List<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();
for(...){//decide how many to add
   Player player = new Player();
   player.getSurname();
   player.getFirstName();
   player.getAge();
   player.getHeight();
   player.getRank();
   players.add(player);
}
...//use the Player objects in players
```